# Getting User Likes Count

Tags: php, sql, facebook-fql

I want to get user's friend's total page like counts

When i apply fql sentence which is below it results nice on [fql explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

```
SELECT 
  uid, 
  name, 
  likes_count 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT 
                uid1, 
                uid2 
              FROM friend 
              WHERE uid1=me())
```

[image: nice result]
But, when i do the same thing with php it doesn't show likes_counts.
**php code:**

```
$fql= 'SELECT uid, name, likes_count FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid1, uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())';
$ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
        'method' => 'fql.query',
        'query' => $fql,
        'access_token'=> ''.$fbme[access_token].''
)); 
print_r($ret_obj);
```

**php result:**

[image]

How can i show like_counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the permissions you have in `fql explorer` are not similar to those you requested when setting up the FB session in your PHP.

Comment: how can we do this from graph api?